# Term for the water/wine ratio chooser?

Tags: word-request, roman-culture

What's the Latin word for the person at cena who decided whether more or less water was added to the wine to keep the party going steadily?

Comment: Interesting question! Have you read somewhere that there was a person with this duty? Any indication of the origin of this idea might help find a word in the literature.

Comment: @Joonas - It was actually information that a professor provided during a lecture years ago, and my brain was itching to recall the term. They correlated it with a modern bartender.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The Latin term for this is ***magister bibendi*** or ***arbiter bibendi***, or "master of drinking."  Here's some context:

> After a roll of the dice, a magister bibendi was chosen.  By appointing a certain ratio of water to wine to be mixed in the cups, this so-called "master of the drinking" then decided the strength of the wine to be drunk. ([*Latin for Dummies*](https://books.google.com/books?id=Jmdmv6sjSEoC&pg=PT141&lpg=PT141&dq="magister+bibendi"))

And in [*A Companion to Latin Studies*, §250](https://books.google.com/books?id=6q0MAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA207):

> Drinking at the *cena* was moderate, but it was frequently followed by a drinking bout called *cōmissatio*.  One of the guests was chosen *magister* or *arbiter bibendi*, and his function was to decide the respective proportions of wine and water.

Horace mentions the latter option in [*Odes*, 2.7](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0024%3Abook%3D2%3Apoem%3D7):

> curatve myrto? quem Venus **arbitrum
>
>   dicet bibendi?** non ego sanius
>   bacchabor Edonis: recepto
>   dulce mihi furere est amico.
>
> Who’ll throw high Venus at dice and so become
>   **the master of drink**? I’ll rage as insanely
>   as any Thracian: It’s sweet to me
>   to revel when a friend is home again. ([translation source](http://www.poetryintranslation.com/PITBR/Latin/HoraceOdesBkII.htm#anchor_Toc39742781))

Comment: As a supplement to this, the Vulgate uses the Greek term to refer to the "master of the feast": [architriclinus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Darchitriclinus)

Comment: Interesting!  I wonder what the difference is between that and *symposiarchos*, which is what I found corresponding in Greek.

Comment: Wonderful, the sources for context makes it all the more interesting and helpful!

Comment: @Nathaniel I've just spent 30 miins looking this up before I saw your excellent answer! ؛-)

Comment: @Nathaniel I don't know about the magister bibendi, but the symposiarch had charge of a number of aspects of the evening: not just the water-to-wine ratio and how many cups were to be drunk, but also things like what the entertainment/activity was to be to accompany each round of drinking (riddles? word-play? quoting?) and so on.